# A single gate defined in Conjunctive Normal Form

Tags: logic

This might sound like a silly question but I just want to make sure I'm not getting confused.

I understand that CNF is essentially converting the logic into AND's of OR's, so for example...

~a AND (b OR c) in CNF would be (a AND b) OR (a AND c).

My question is, what would a single and gate be defined as in CNF. So for example if it had 2 inputs and 1 output, x y z . Would x AND y in CNF just be x AND y?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "Yes, a single literal is in CNF" (also in DNF for that matter).  CNF means an AND clause consisting of OR clauses (which each consist of potentially negated literals).

In you current example

```
~a AND (b OR c) in CNF would be (a AND b) OR (a AND c).
```

the first formulation is CNF, the second DNF (disjunctive normal form).

Answer (score 0):

[CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) stands for *Conjunctive Normal Form*.

A boolean expression is in [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) if it is an `AND` of `OR` expressions where every `OR` has nothing but literals or inverted literals as inputs. The `OR` expressions for [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) are commonly called *clauses*.

Your example:

The [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) of **x AND y** consists of two single-literal clauses, one is **x** and one is **y**.